# How can I apply a constant current at the drain to source terminal of a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, current

How can I apply a constant current of 125 µA to the drain to source terminals of a MOSFET? I already have a voltage supply at the gate. Should I get another current source or is there another way to utilize just the voltage supply I have? We are applying the circuit in an Arduino system.

Comment: `... utilize just the voltage supply i have` give more info about the supply you have i.e. voltage, current, where it's coming from (such as USB or a PSU etc). `... drain to source terminal of a MOSFET` what MOSFET? Put a link to its datasheet.

Comment: I can think of several answers, but which you need depends on how you want to configure the FET. I'm also having difficulty understanding the 'drain to source' terminal of a FET. Add a schematic of what you want to your question, using the built-in schematic editor, using a generic current source symbol where you want the current source to be.

Comment: At what Vds? Why should Vgs be fixed? Is this a follow-on to your previous question?

Comment: Does it have to be 125 μA, or could you accept 100 (or 200) μA? If 100 or 200 μA works, the REF200 is a single-chip solution here.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of feeding a current through this transistor? are you looking to make a common-source amplifier? A professor of mine in analog circuit design (IEEE fellow and all that) used to have a mantra: "you can't fix a current through the transistor's drain!"; the reason being that you need to feedback to keep the current and its gate voltage fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that drain current \$I_D\$ and source current \$I_S\$ must necessarily be equal, you can use the circuit from my [answer to your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/670990/292884), and set \$R_1=20k\Omega\$. This will obtain the condition \$I_D=I_S=125\mu A\$.

If you insist on sourcing current from the high side, down into the drain, you are implementing a setup shown below left. The blue-boxed section (the actual current source) is implemented on the right, using a design called the [Howland Current Pump](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-howland-current-pump/):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE4HhC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Be aware that you'll need a 2.5V reference for this to work, which I obtained in my other answer using a TL431. You can do the same thing here.

Below left is another, slightly more complex source, with improved maximum compliance voltage (the maximum voltage it's able to apply to the top of the load, your MOSFET drain). On the right is a much simpler source, but also much less precise:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjbkQr.png)</sup>

Even though I've used a supply of +12V, all of these designs should work with supplies down to +5V. The use of a rail-to-rail output op-amp, such as the TLC2272, is probably necessary. This *rules out* the popular LM324, LM358, TL07x and TL08x models.

Finally, if component count is important, you can use a commercial precision current source IC, like the [LM334](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/134sfc.pdf). The following is taken from the zero-temperature coefficient example on page 7, with component values chosen to obtain 125μA:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFvTRj.png)</sup>